# How do I extract the coredata of a zoo object into a data frame?

Tags: dataframe, zoo

32I have several zoo ordered observations that contain data indexed by date. For example (HTML used for spacing):

A           B
2014-10-5   60.272 84.019
2014-10-6   61.183 84.024
2014-10-7   61.611 84.010

A           B
2014-10-5   61.376 84.028
2014-10-6   61.761 84.032
2014-10-7   62.210 84.025

A           B
2014-10-5   61.159 84.006
2014-10-6   61.550 84.029
2014-10-7   61.996 84.024

I have 3 of these objects, say, x, y, and z, with different data in each.

I want to extract data (from last row) from these and put them into a non-zoo data frame because I no longer want the date indexing. Here is what I tried to do:

```
main.result <- data.frame(x[nrow(x),])
main.result <- data.frame(rbind(main.result, y[nrow(y),]))
main.result <- data.frame(rbind(main.result, z[nrow(z),]))
```

What is get is not what I expected in main.result:

A                                    B
main.result 61.61163, 62.21080  84.02096, 84.02505
                                   61.99627                              84.02423

I should have gotten:

A        B
 61.611  84.010
 62.210  84.025
 61.996  84.024

I want to continue to add rows to the main.result matrix. Where am I jumping the track here?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

SOLVED: Sorry, the formatting of the output for ‘main.result’ threw me off. The answer I am getting is correct. Please disregard this post!!